# cypher connections to a group of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

With this cypher query I'm able to find all nodes that I want

```
 match (t:FacebookPage)-[l:LIKED_BY]-(p:FacebookPost)-[r:WRITTEN_BY]-(n:FacebookAccount)
    where n.facebookId IN ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"] 
    return t,l,p,r,n
```

Now I would like a subset of theese nodes:
the t-nodes that are connected to more than one distinct n-node.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: added an example where you return all relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `WITH` and `WHERE` clause to do additional filtering. Like so

```
match (t:FacebookPage)-[l:LIKED_BY]-(p:FacebookPost)-[r:WRITTEN_BY]-(n:FacebookAccount)
where n.facebookId IN ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
with t,count(distinct(n)) as count where count > 1
return t
```

If you want to return all relationships I think you must do two `MATCH` clause, because filtering works depending on what your return(aggregate)

```
match (t:FacebookPage)-[l:LIKED_BY]-(p:FacebookPost)-[r:WRITTEN_BY]-(n:FacebookAccount)
where n.facebookId IN ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
with t,count(distinct(n)) as count where count > 1
match (t)-[l1:LIKED_BY]-(p1:FacebookPost)-[r1:WRITTEN_BY]-(n1:FacebookAccount)
return t,l1,p1,r1,n1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you please explain also why `with t,l,p,r,n,count(distinct(n)) as count where count > 1
return t,l,p,r,n` does not return records?

Comment: if you return only `t,count(n)` then it aggregates by `t` and there will be more counts per t. If you return everything or use with, it does not aggregate data, so the count will always be 1